# Find consumer demand as a function of time, given the demand equation and price

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, economics

> An importer of Brazilian coffee estimates that local consumers will buy approximately $Q(p)= 4374/p^2$ kg of the coffee per week when the price is $p$ dollars per kg. It is estimated that $t$ weeks from now the price of this coffee will be $p(t) = 0.04t^2 + 0.2t + 12$ dollar per kg.
>
> a) Express the weekly consumer demand for the coffee as a function of $t$.
>
> b) How many kg of the coffee will consumers be buying from the importer $10$ weeks from now?
>
> c) When will the demand for the coffee be $30.375$ kg?

Here's my solution
a)
\begin{align*}
q(p) & = \frac{4374}{p^2} p^{-2}\\
     & = 4374 -2 p^{-3}\\ 
     & = \frac{4372}{p^3}
\end{align*}
and I don't really know how please help me

Comment: Is this homework? Maybe you should first consult your textbook. If you have no clue at all, a solution copied here from some answer will not help you in the long run. (Ok, I guess you are not interested in it)

Comment: Now I am totally confused. The question was about air pollution, suddenly now it is about coffee. Is coffee a pollutant? Maybe the OP could decide what he wants to ask?

Comment: @Karl. What would you prefer : smog or coffee ? Cheers :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$Q$ is a function of $p$, and $p$ is a function of $t$. What do you get when you insert the expression $p=0.04t^2+0.2t+12$ into $Q$?